# boost::async_write skips parts of the string

Tags: c++, boost

I am working on a chat. For some reason, at the point of distributing user's message between other clients, string put together by `Server::msgHandler` is butchered by `async_write` in `Connection::write`, making it appear as only the part of that string has actually been read. Example:

> Constructed message: "Hello people by Jack"
>   Appears as: "by Jack"

that is the `string str=Hello people` is not printed out. At first I thought it was to do with the implicit `\0` at its end, but that wouldn't make any sense, moreover, as I tried various positions of string in message I noticed that if  `str` is preceded with other text, the text will be shown either emitting `str` entirely, or placing it in unexpected places. E.g.

> `writeMsg("It was said: \n"+str+" by \"name\"\n");`
>   will appear as: 
>   It was said
>      by "name"Hello People

Full, minimal, compilable example:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

typedef boost::asio::io_service io_service;
typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp tcp;

class Server;

class Connection : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Connection> {
    io_service::strand strand;
    tcp::socket soc;
    std::deque<std::string> msgBuff;
    boost::asio::streambuf buf;
    Server* server;
    void(Server::*serverHandler)(std::string);

private:
    Connection(io_service& service) :soc(service), strand(service){

    }

    void writeStranded(std::string msg){
        msgBuff.push_back(msg);
        if (msgBuff.size() > 1)return;
        write();

    }
    void write(){
        std::string& tmpMsg = msgBuff[0];
        boost::asio::async_write(
            soc,
            boost::asio::buffer(tmpMsg.c_str(), tmpMsg.size()),
            strand.wrap(
            boost::bind(&Connection::handleWrite,
                this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
                )
        ); 
    }
    void handleWrite(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t s){
        msgBuff.pop_front();
        if (!msgBuff.empty())write();
    }
    void handleRead(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t s){
        std::istream is(&buf);
        std::string tmpMsg;
        std::getline(is, tmpMsg);

        (server->*serverHandler)(tmpMsg);
        readMsg();
    }


public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Connection> pointer;
    static  pointer createInstance(io_service& service){
        return pointer(new Connection(service));
    }

    void init(Server* server, void(Server::*serverHandler)(std::string)){
        this->server = server;
        this->serverHandler = serverHandler; 
        writeMsg("hello\n");
        readMsg();
    }

    void writeMsg(std::string msg){
        strand.dispatch(boost::bind(&Connection::writeStranded, this, msg));
    }

    void readMsg(){
        const char delim = '\n';
        boost::asio::async_read_until(soc, buf, delim,
            boost::bind(&Connection::handleRead, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    }

    tcp::socket& getSocket(){
        return soc;
    }

};

class Server{
    tcp::acceptor accept;
    std::vector<Connection::pointer> connections;

public:
    Server(io_service& io_service, int port = 23) :accept(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)){
        awaitConnection();
    };


private:
    void awaitConnection(){
        Connection::pointer con = Connection::createInstance(accept .get_io_service());
        accept.async_accept(con->getSocket(), boost::bind(&Server::conAcceptor, this, con, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    void conAcceptor(Connection::pointer con, const boost::system::error_code& err){
        if (err)return;
        con->init(this, &Server::msgHandler);
        awaitConnection();
        connections.push_back(con);
    }
    void msgHandler(std::string str){
        for (Connection::pointer ptr : connections){
            ptr->writeMsg(str+" by \"name\"\n");
        }
    }

};


int main(){
    io_service io_service;
    Server s(io_service);
    io_service.run();
    system("pause");

}
```

**Upd**
Turns out the `async_read` was appending the string with carriage return, which was stored as it was added before the delimeter in the `name` string, and each time I tried make the name appear, everything preceding it would get overwritten by all that followed. Sometimes that carriage return would get wild and skip some characters preceding the name, which further complicated the search of this bug.

Comment: I recommend initialising boost::asio::streambuf buf`` with some memory in the `Connection` constructor... ;)

Comment: @kenba `streambuf ` has no constructors, nor functions, defined for allocating memory to its objects, so I don't really know what you are saying. I do not use `basic_streambuf`

Comment: `streambuf`` is an instance of [basic_streambuf](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/basic_streambuf.html). The `Connection`constructor does not allocate any memory for the receive buffer: `buf`. Do you understand now?

Comment: @kenba, I added `buf(1024)` to my `Connection` constructor, nothing changed. But I won't claim I know how to allocate memorry

Comment: That is the correct way to allocate memory for the buffer. Have you looked at the asio Chat example [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I got it running. I had to write a client for it...

Before this goes into production you'll want to look at the lifetime handling. The normal way is that the connection object holds a shared_ptr to itself in its bound handlers.

I have use c++14 lambdas as I find them less onerous that boost::bind.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>

typedef boost::asio::io_service io_service;
typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp    tcp;

class Server;

class Connection
    : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Connection>
{
    io_service::strand strand;
    tcp::socket        soc;

    // use double-buffering for the message sending
    std::deque<std::string> sending, to_send;

    boost::asio::streambuf buf;
    Server                 *server;

    void (Server::*serverHandler)(std::string);

private:
    Connection(io_service& service)
        : strand(service)
        , soc(service)
    {

    }

    void writeStranded(std::string msg)
    {
        assert(strand.running_in_this_thread());  // sanity check
        to_send.push_back(std::move(msg));
        maybe_write();

    }

    void maybe_write()
    {
        assert(strand.running_in_this_thread());  // sanity check
        if (sending.empty() and not to_send.empty()) {
            sending.swap(to_send);

            // make a buffer sequence

            auto buffers = std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffers_1>();
            buffers.reserve(sending.size());
            for (auto& data : sending) {
                buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(data));
            }
            boost::asio::async_write(soc, buffers,
                                     strand.wrap([this](auto&& ec, size_t size)
                                                 {
                                                     this->sending.clear();
                                                     if (not ec) maybe_write();
                                                 }));
        }
    }

    void handleRead(const boost::system::error_code&, size_t s)
    {
        std::istream is(&buf);
        std::string  tmpMsg;
        std::getline(is, tmpMsg);

        (server->*serverHandler)(tmpMsg);
        readMsg();
    }


public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Connection> pointer;

    static pointer createInstance(io_service& service)
    {
        return pointer(new Connection(service));
    }

    void init(Server *server, void(Server::*serverHandler)(std::string))
    {
        this->server        = server;
        this->serverHandler = serverHandler;
        writeMsg("hello\n");
        readMsg();
    }

    void writeMsg(std::string msg)
    {
        strand.dispatch(boost::bind(&Connection::writeStranded, this, msg));
    }

    void readMsg()
    {
        const char delim = '\n';
        boost::asio::async_read_until(soc, buf, delim,
                                      boost::bind(&Connection::handleRead, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                  boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    }

    tcp::socket& getSocket()
    {
        return soc;
    }

};

class Server
{
    tcp::acceptor                    accept;
    std::vector<Connection::pointer> connections;

public:
    Server(io_service& io_service, int port = 2333)
        : accept(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
    {
        awaitConnection();
    };


private:
    void awaitConnection()
    {
        Connection::pointer con = Connection::createInstance(accept.get_io_service());
        accept.async_accept(con->getSocket(),
                            boost::bind(&Server::conAcceptor, this, con, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void conAcceptor(Connection::pointer con, const boost::system::error_code& err)
    {
        if (err)return;
        con->init(this, &Server::msgHandler);
        awaitConnection();
        connections.push_back(con);
    }

    void msgHandler(std::string str)
    {
        for (Connection::pointer ptr : connections) {
            ptr->writeMsg(str + " by \"name\"\n");
        }
    }

};

struct Client
{
    using protocol = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

    Client(boost::asio::io_service& exec)
        : executor_(exec) {}


    void run(int port)
    {

        resolver_.async_resolve(protocol::resolver::query("localhost", std::to_string(port)),
                                strand_.wrap([this](auto&& ec, auto iter)
                                             {
                                                 std::cout << "resolve: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                                                 if (not ec) start_connect(iter);
                                             }));

    }

    void start_connect(protocol::resolver::iterator iter)
    {
        boost::asio::async_connect(socket_, iter,
                                   strand_.wrap([this](auto&& ec, auto iter)
                                                {
                                                    std::cout << "connect: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                                                    if (not ec) {
                                                        this->start_reading();
                                                        auto data = std::make_shared<std::string>(
                                                            "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n"
                                                                "Farmer bob has a cool tractor\n");
                                                        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(*data),
                                                                                 strand_
                                                                                     .wrap([data](auto&& ec, auto size)
                                                                                           {
                                                                                               std::cout << "written: "
                                                                                                         << size
                                                                                                         << std::endl;
                                                                                           }));
                                                    }
                                                }));
    }

    void start_reading()
    {
        auto buffer = read_buffer_.prepare(1024);
        socket_.async_read_some(read_buffer_.prepare(1024), [this](auto&& ec, auto size)
        {
            read_buffer_.commit(size);
            std::istream is(std::addressof(read_buffer_));
            std::string s;
            while(std::getline(is, s)) {
                std::cout << s << std::endl;
            }
            start_reading();
        });

    }

    boost::asio::io_service& executor_;
    boost::asio::io_service::strand strand_{executor_};
    protocol::resolver              resolver_{executor_};
    protocol::socket                socket_{executor_};
    boost::asio::streambuf          read_buffer_;
};

int main()
{
    io_service io_service;
    Server     s(io_service);
    Client     c(io_service);
    c.run(2333);
    io_service.run();
    system("pause");

}
```

output (program does not terminate):

```
resolve: Undefined error: 0
connect: Undefined error: 0
written: 74
hello
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog by "name"
Farmer bob has a cool tractor by "name"
```

Comment: Additional cues are much appreciated, thank you. I will review it tomorrow

Comment: I incorporated the tweaks you introduced to `Connection` ignoring the client side as I use Telnet to reach server. This did not solve my problem. The strings still overlay @RichardH

Comment: @Michael.P interesting. I'll take a look tonight

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in `void readMsg()`    `delim` is set to be `'\n'`. As innocuous as it might look it doesn't take into account the fact that **in Windows a newline is represented as CR + LF which is: "*\r\n*"**. So each time you read something from socket using `read_until(delim)` everything besides delimeter will stay in the buffer, including `\r` (carriage return). If string like that is later appended it is expected that everything after `\r` will overlay the original text.